# Use of GlobalSuppressions.cs i StyleCop Runner in Azure Pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, stylecop

I have a c# solution that adhere to our custom StyleCop rules as specified in `stylecop.json` and `GlobalSuppresions.cs`. Both are located in the solution root and linked each project via their `.csproj` files.

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline set up to build the entire solution and also run StyleCop on it using the runner. However, although our `stylecop.json` settings are respected by the runner, the `GlobalSuppresions.cs` ones aren't. In the runner there is an option to specify a path for a settings file, but none for `GlobalSuppresions.cs`.

The question is: Is there a way to make the runner understand `GlobalSuppressions.cs`? Or is there a way to merge our rules into `stylecop.json`?

Answer (score 1):

So... since I wrote the questions I've learned a couple of things.

In newer versions of Visual Studio the "[Roslyn Analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2017)" are supposed to be used. While the [stylecop analyzers nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/stylecop.analyzers/) adhere to `GlobalSuppressions.cs`, and automatically create such files when requested via code fixes, that is not the recommended approach. Instead [rulesets should be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2017). Rulesets are different from stylecop settings files which come in a new and old version. The new version is the .json one.

Rulesets are understood by the compiler directly, so there is no longer a need for the [Azure DevOps build task that we were using](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-StyleCop-Task). I simply created a ruleset that matched what we had in `GlobalSuppressions.cs` and started using that for development. For our release configuration, which is what we use on Azure DevOps I created a copy of the ruleset, but with all the rules we use set to *Error* rather than *Warning*.